# Additive group of reals saturated

Tags: group-theory, model-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$ be the additive group of reals. Is this structure $\aleph_0$-saturated?

I don't really see how to go about showing this. To show it is not saturated, it is enough to exhibit a type omitted in $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$. The interesting statements we can make about groups are usually to do with torsion or divisibility, but I can't see a way to find a type omitted in $(\mathbb{R}, +, 0)$ from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every (nontrivial) torsion-free divisible group has a structure of $\Bbb Q$-vector space. This shows that the theory $T$ of torsion-free divisible group is uncountably categorical (because a vector space is identified up to isomorphism by its dimension, and all the uncountable $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces have the same dimension). Suppose that $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ is *not* $\aleph_0$-saturated. Then some type $p$ would be omitted in $(\Bbb R,+,0)$, but by Lowenheim-Skolem one would be able to find a model of $T$ of size $|\Bbb R|$ that realizes $p$, and this model would not be isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,+,0)$*. This contradicts the fact that $T$ is $|\Bbb R|$-categorical.

*One has to use the ultrahomogeneity of $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ for this argument to work, as explained by Alex in the comments below. Ultrahomogeneity of $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ follows from linear algebra: given two families $\overline a$ and $\overline b$ that satisfy the same formulas, there exists an automorphism of $(\Bbb R,+,0)$ that takes $\overline a$ to $\overline b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: The type has finitely many parameters, or alternatively, it is just a parameter-free $n$-type for some integer $n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments - somehow I misread $\aleph_0$-saturated as $\aleph_1$-saturated! But yes, you're missing something in this argument. Saying that $M$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated means that any type $p(x)$ over finitely many parameters $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ is realized. In your comment, you suggest eliminating the parameters by writing $p$ as $p'(x,a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and looking at the $(n+1)$-type $p'(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$. Maybe this is realized in $M$ by a tuple $c,b_1,\dots,b_n$, i.e. $p(x,b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is realized in $M$. Why should $p(x,a_1,\dots,a_n)$ be realized in $M$?

Comment: You can fix this argument in 3 ways: 1. Use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces are very homogeneous (by linear algebra) to find an automorphism moving $\overline{b}$ to $\overline{a}$. 2. Show that *some* $\aleph_0$-saturated model of size $|\mathbb{R}|$ exists and hence, by uncountable categoricity, $(\mathbb{R},+,0)$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated. 3. Appeal to the much stronger fact that all uncountable models of uncountably categorical theories are saturated. But this takes a little more work (you need $\omega$-stability).

Comment: (or use the very elementary argument in my answer)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ohh, I see! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Note, as in Zarathustra's answer, that $(\mathbb{R},0,+)$ carries the structure of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. What are the possible types over $A$?

For every $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of elements of $A$, there is a type $p(x)$ which is completely determined by the formula asserting that $x$ is equal to that linear combination (this is not strictly a formula in the language $\{0,+\}$, but it is equivalent to one by clearing denominators and interpreting scalar multiplication by integers as repeated addition). All of these types are realized in $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations..

I claim there is just one other type over $A$. It suffices to show that if $a$ and $b$ are any two elements of some elementary extension $R$, such that neither is in the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $A$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same type over $A$. This follows by from the fact that there is an automorphism of $R$ fixing $A$ and moving $a$ to $b$, obtained by linear algebra: pick a basis for the span of $A$, then extend this basis to a basis for $R$ in two different ways, one containing $a$ and one containing $b$.

This last type is also realized in $\mathbb{R}$, since the span of $A$ is countable, while $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. Any element of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not in the span of $A$ satisfies it.

Note that the same argument works whenever $|A|<|\mathbb{R}|$, which shows that this structure is saturated, not just $\aleph_0$-saturated.